# IOException: Bad file descriptor in Linux

Tags: java, linux, file-io, ioexception

Getting `Bad file descriptor` exception while running Java application in Linux environment which can run fine in windows. below is the code:

```
Properties ProgramConfig = new Properties();
        try
        {
            InputStream in = new FileInputStream("application.properties");

            //loading properties file now
            ProgramConfig.load(in);

            IpAddressPort = ProgramConfig.getProperty("ip");
            System.out.println("Ip address "+IpAddressPort);


        }
```

Comment: try with `syncronized{ ProgramConfig.load(in); }`

Comment: Please supply an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/MCVE)